# What is the difference between ${spring.version} and literal version number

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I saw many tutorial some people use maven `dependency` such way

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and some people use maven `dependency` such way

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

What is the main difference between `<version>${spring.version}</version>` and `<version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>` in maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation of `${spring.version}` is a POM variable. This means that somewhere in POM (or in one of parent POMs), you'll see a definition similar to this:

```
<spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

They both achieve the same end result, but using variables is a bit easier to maintain, especially if you use several artifacts sharing the same version. This way, when you choose to upgrade them, you only need to change the version in one place instead of once per artifact.

Comment: your  answer is really help me.Thank you very much